# merge CTE query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I am looking for an optimized way to merge CTE query as mentioned below. In the below query, the same table is getting hit twice, I am looking for an option to hit this table once and it will only be possible if I remove CTE and put everything into single query. I am using CTE as I need to derive column value and then compare that value..

**Query**

```
with cte as 
(
    select distinct                                               
        'UP' search_update_code, 
        'G' search_prov_entity_type, 
        prpr.prpr_id search_prov_id,  
        prpr.mctn_id search_tax_id, 
        'UP' group_provdata_upd_cd, 
        'G' group_provdata_entity, 
        case  
           when enroll_type = 'AH' THEN 'A'
           when enroll_type = 'VP' THEN 'A'
           when enroll_type = 'CK' THEN ' ' 
       end group_provdata_clm_eft_pay_ind  <-- deriving values here
   from  
       fsg_prcb_pe_enroll_stream prcb                                          
   inner join 
       cmc_prpr_prov prpr on prpr.mctn_id = prcb.prov_tin_number     <-- 1st hit
   where 
       prpr.prpr_entity ='G' 
       and prcb.prov_tin_number = ?
       and prcb.error_flag is null
)
select distinct 
    cte.* 
from cte                                               
inner join cmc_prpr_prov prpr on cte.search_prov_id = prpr.prpr_id    <-- 2nd hit
where cte.group_provdata_clm_eft_pay_ind <> prpr.prpr_cl_eft_ind <--- comparing derived values here
  and prpr_term_dt >= systimestamp
```

Comment: You have two completly different join predicates; `prpr.mctn_id = prcb.prov_tin_number` and `cte.search_prov_id = prpr.prpr_id`. How do you expect this can be covered with one join?

Comment: You can select prpr_cl_eft_ind  in your CTE and ...

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query like below:

```
with cte as 
(
    select distinct                                               
        'UP' search_update_code, 
        'G' search_prov_entity_type, 
        prpr.prpr_id search_prov_id,  
        prpr.mctn_id search_tax_id, 
        'UP' group_provdata_upd_cd, 
        'G' group_provdata_entity, 
        case  
           when enroll_type = 'AH' THEN 'A'
           when enroll_type = 'VP' THEN 'A'
           when enroll_type = 'CK' THEN ' ' 
       end group_provdata_clm_eft_pay_ind,  <-- deriving values here
       prpr.prpr_cl_eft_ind prpr_cl_eft_ind_2,
       prpr_term_dt 
   from  
       fsg_prcb_pe_enroll_stream prcb                                          
   inner join 
       cmc_prpr_prov prpr on prpr.mctn_id = prcb.prov_tin_number     <-- 1st hit
   where 
       prpr.prpr_entity ='G' 
       and prcb.prov_tin_number = ?
       and prcb.error_flag is null
)
select distinct 
    cte.* 
from cte                                               
where  group_provdata_clm_eft_pay_ind <> prpr_cl_eft_ind_2 <--- comparing derived values here
  and prpr_term_dt >= systimestamp
```